# Make url match '/', '/index' and '/index.html' to a single state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've trying to make the following urls point to the same state, but only two are working.

- http://path.com/ ✔
- http://path.com/index ✔
- http://path.com/index.html  ✘

  ```
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/{index}',
      controller: 'HomeController',
  });
  ```

On the [$stateProvider docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), it says the `url` uses the [UrlMatcher pattern](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher), but none of the 
patterns seem to match watch I'm aiming.

So, how do you make the latter works?

Thanks!

Comment: I would not worry about making the 2nd and 3rd work and instead have a redirect on backend that redirects both 2nd and 3rd to the first.

Comment: @KevinB thanks, but we're looking for a front-end solution.

Comment: `http://path.com/` serves your index.html, correct? What exactly happens when you request the index.html directly?

Comment: Actually I forgot to check other paths, but as Sulthan pointed. even '/dummy' was leading to the home. 
@KevinB thanks for taking your time to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/{index}` is not what you think it is. It defines a state for `/` with a parameter `{index}`. So I am pretty sure it will also capture for example `/dummy`.

I think you want to define a simple state using `/`, e.g.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeController',
});
```

And then use ui-router redirects (taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing))

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){   
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/index.html', '/');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/index', '/');
})
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked, made a few edits to your question just for the url to behave the way I was expecting.